# Traversing an Object with PHP

Tags: php

I've made a successful API call and retrieved a JSON response which I've ran through json_decode(). I can traverse and return the value fine, however I need a way of entering the first parent without specifying it. I've tried just empty `[]` but that didn't work. Is there a way that I can do this?

For reference the obj I get is:

```
(
    [C:\path\file.html] => stdClass Object
        (
            [message] => FAIL
            [errors] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [severity] => ERROR
                            [line] => 23
                        )
                        ......
```

I need a way of getting to the 'message' WITHOUT declaring the `c:\path\file.html`.

Currently I can return it fine if i do specify it.

`$obj[C:\path\file.html]['message']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is only one then get the first one:

```
$obj = reset($obj);
//or
$obj = current($obj);
//then
$message = $obj->message;
```

Or:

```
echo reset($obj)->message;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `foreach` cycle.

```
foreach ($obj as $row) {
    echo $row['message']; // fail
}
```

If you need key (file location), use

```
foreach ($obj as $key => $row) {
    echo $row['message']; // fail
    // echo $key; // C:/path/file.html
}
```